# Prevent custom django admin url from redirecting to change view

Tags: django, django-admin

I have defined a custom django admin url that I am using as a custom action link in the changelist view and will also be used by the form posted in that custom view.

```
# used in the overridden changelist.html
<a href="{% url 'admin:get_monthly_report' %}">Get Monthly Report</a>

# in the model admin
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()

    urls += [
        path(
            'get_monthly_report/',
            self.admin_site.admin_view(self.get_monthly_report),
            name='get_monthly_report'
        ),
    ]
    return urls
```

Problem is clicking on the link keeps trying to redirect the change view (doesn't make sense why Django is trying to guess instead of using the actual view defined for the URL). Given that what am doing is close enough to what is suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls), either the documentation left this problem out or am doing something wrong
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URL path from `get_monthly_report/` to `get_monthly_report` fixed the problem.
Am still looking forward to a 'Djangonic' explanation of what was happening.